# Need a Regular expresssion that should not allow only space in string, It can allow spaces along with characters

Tags: regex

Need a Regular expresssion that should not allow  only space  in string, It can allow spaces along  with characters.

e.g: space+char+space  is  allowed  where  as  only  space  is not allowed

Comment: Regexes vary somewhat by language - it would be good to mention and tag what language you're using this regex for.

Comment: Varma, if one of these answers worked for you, please come and accept the answer.

Answer (score 6):

`/\S/` is sufficient to match a non-empty string.

Comment: @Emily in elisp, one would use "\\S-"

Comment: I think elisp probably fits into the "almost". It's a bit of an odd character ;)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
/^\s+$\
```

Any string that matches the above expression is invalid as per your criteria.

Comment: This won't allow a trailing space, which is mentioned as valid

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's easier and faster to test the emptiness of the string after using trim() on it.

Comment: I don't know that we can assume a trim method is available in the language the OP is using

Comment: @Tomalak  you are still making assumptions about the language parsing the regular expression.  I didn't assume that the OP was using sed.  However escaped characters are pretty standard in most parsers

Comment: @dusktreader I did not assume anything either, especially not sed. I just chose a compact regex notation to get my point across - which is that you can trim a string with regex.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for a positive match:

```
/\S/
```

If you want to capture:

```
/(.*\S.*)/
```

**EDIT**:

Actually, if you meant a *literal* space:

```
/[ ]/
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to enforce a non-space character appearing at least once:

\s*\S+\s*